# How do you manage foreign key relations for newly generated keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, mysql-8.0

### Background

I have two tables `Parent` and `Child`. The relationship is one-to-many parent ids to children ids. So, to optimize routine `JOIN` queries, I'm considering defining a foreign key by

```
ALTER TABLE Child
  ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY
  parent_id
  REFERENCES Parent (id);
```

where `Parent.id` is a `PRIMARY KEY`. By not explicitly setting an `ON UPDATE` or an `ON DELETE` clause I believe I have implicitly set the default of

```
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

per [MySQL 8.0 Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). Note that `Child.parent_id` is indexed.

But the situation is such that the `Child` table will be frequently updated *before* the `Parent` table and it will sometimes have new data regarding `Parent` with never-before-seen foreign keys of `Child.parent_id`. This is because the `Child` table is a near-instant log of transaction-like records which are the only input to the database; the `Parent` table is a derived and consolidated summary of the `Child` table that is tasked to update every few hours.

Now, reading other posts, I've read that a `FOREIGN KEY` requires the referenced column of the parent table to be unique *and to exist*. Clearly I have no issue with uniqueness, since my referenced parent column is a `PRIMARY KEY`, my issue is with *existence* of a referential value. In a question: what happens when I insert a new record into the `Child` table which contains a never-before-seen `Child.parent_id`?

### Experiment

I tested this on two smaller tables, both created in the image of the larger tables that I wish this to optimize (with a `CREATE TABLE Parent LIKE...`, etc.). The naming of these test tables is as described above. With the creation of these small test tables I defined a `FOREIGN KEY` on the test tables exactly as above.

So `Parent` looks something like:

```
| id    | SummaryStat1 | SummaryStat2 | ... | SummaryStatN        |
|-------|--------------|--------------|-----|---------------------|
| 147   | 50.4         | 1999983      | ... | NULL                |
| 99384 | 60.8         | 3592324      | ... | 2018-03-05 00:22:09 |
| ...   |              |              |     |                     |
```

And `Child` like:

```
| id          | parent_id | Stat1 | ... | StatM               |
|-------------|-----------|-------|-----|---------------------|
| 1           | 147       | 18.3  | ... | 2018-02-17 14:23:10 |
| 2           | 99384     | 0.02  | ... | 2018-02-17 14:23:12 |
| (AUTO INCR) | ...       | ...   | ... | ...                 |
| 70565       | 147       |       |     | 2018-02-18 16:59:00 |
| ...         | ...       | ...   | ... | ...                 |
```

So, after setting the `FOREIGN KEY` I inserted a new record into `Child` with a never-before-seen `Child.parent_id` and the database issues the expected complaint:

```
"Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails..."
```

Is there a well known work around for this? I'm considering modifying the transaction process to insert a default `Parent` record with the new `Parent.id` *before* data is sent to the `Child` table, but it would be nice if there was a simple DB solution, like an option that allows you to store disconnected foreign key values until the parent foreign key appears in the parent table.

Comment: There is no such thing as `disconnected foreign key` - the database imposes the integrity constraints at all times. You can set `child.parent_id` to NULL until the parent is created.

Comment: But then how would you update the `child.parent_id` when the parent is created?

Comment: I think you have the child and parent reverse.

Comment: If I set the `child.parent_id` to  `NULL`, and then create the parent, there will be no immediate way to connect the parent back to that child. I get child information only, parent information must be derived from that parent information.

Comment: Sorry, a correction: "...parent information must be derived from the child table."

Comment: Well, the cleanest solution is to always create the parent before your child - since you know the ID of the parent. But if you do not want this - you can create a new column in the `child` table where you will store the ID of the parent but this column will not be a foreign key. Then later, when you create the row in table `parent` - you can simply update all `child.parent_id` (the foreign key) whose `original_parent_id` matches the ID of the just created parent. I hope you understand the idea.

Answer (score 1):

No 'simple' solution.

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO parent ...
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id);
$parent_id = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO child
    ( ..., parent_id, ... )
    VALUES
    ( ..., $parent_id, ... )
COMMIT;
```